# Pytorch CTC Loss Unexpected Behaviour

Tags: nlp, pytorch

I have used the following code to test the behaviour of CTC loss.

```
from torch.nn import CTCLoss
import torch.nn.functional as fn
import torch
def get_char_maps (vocab):
    char_to_index={}
    index_to_char={}
    cnt=0
    for c in vocab:
        char_to_index[c]=cnt
        index_to_char[cnt]=c
        cnt+=1
    vocab_size=cnt
    return (char_to_index, index_to_char, vocab_size)

loss_function = CTCLoss()
char_to_index, index_to_char, vocab_size = get_char_maps(['~', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', ' '])

empty_char = '~'
label = 'abc'
seq_len = 20
predict = 'abc'
pred_out = predict[0]
for i in range(1, len(predict)):
    if predict[i] == predict[i - 1]:
        pred_out += empty_char + predict[i]
    else:
        pred_out += predict[i]
print(pred_out)
predict = pred_out
label_len = len(label)
left_side = (seq_len - len(predict))//2
right_side = seq_len - left_side - len(predict)
seq_predict = [empty_char]*left_side + list(predict) + [empty_char]*right_side

out = []
for char in seq_predict:
    temp = [0]*vocab_size
    temp[char_to_index[char]] = 1
    out.append([temp])
out = torch.FloatTensor(out)

scores = fn.log_softmax(out, dim=2)
out_size = torch.tensor([seq_len]*1, dtype=torch.int)
y_size = torch.tensor([len(label)], dtype=torch.int)
y = [char_to_index[c] for c in label]
y_var = torch.tensor(y, dtype=torch.int)
l = loss_function(scores, y_var, out_size, y_size)
print(l.item())
```

With this code, when the target is `abc` and the prediction is also `abc`, it produces a loss of `7.770`. However with the same target when the prediction is g, it produces a loss of `7.654`. Which is lower than the perfect prediction. This behaviour seems counterintuitive.
Is this the expected behaviour from CTC loss? Or is this test code has an error?